# What's wrong with this Namespace config in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I am having issues with Namespaces within ActiveAdmin. If I add config settings to a namespace within the initializer I catch a long exception list when attempting to boot of webrick.

I have the following structure:

```
▾ app/
  ▾ admin/
      agents.rb
      dashboards.rb
  ▾ agency/
      agents.rb
      dashboards.rb
```

I don't see a means to set a namespace within the dashboards so as of right now they are both essentially:

```
ActiveAdmin::Dashboards.build do
end
```

The agents have the following declarations:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agent, :namespace=>:agency_admin do
```

and

```
ActiveAdmin.register Agent, :namespace=>:admin do
```

This all works fine with a default config. I can pull up /agency_admin/agents or /admin/agents just fine.  However, as soon as I add a config such as what comes commented out as an example within the initializer:

```
   config.namespace :admin do |admin|
     admin.site_title = "Custom Admin Title"
   end
```

I get the attached exception stream when starting the server. I appreciate any/all help on this.

As an aside, the reason I am doing this is to provide different devise methods per namespace. From what I could tell in the source, it's possible to do so (at least what's on the current master) as the base_controller obtains that information from the namespace. I realize a lot of people recommend using CanCan but that's not something that I want nor can, do at this point.

Thanks again in advance!

```
/Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval': undefined method `devise' for #<Class:0x000001063e9188> (NoMethodError)
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/app/models/user.rb:36:in `<class:User>'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `block in load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/app/helpers/user/addresses_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `block in load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:135:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `map!'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:131:in `modules_for_helpers'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/helpers.rb:89:in `modules_for_helpers'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:95:in `helper'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in with'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `block in load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.2.2/lib/inherited_resources/base.rb:14:in `<module:InheritedResources>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/inherited_resources-1.2.2/lib/inherited_resources/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/base_controller/menu.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/resource_controller/actions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:3:in `<module:Dashboards>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/dashboards/dashboard_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from (eval):1:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `eval'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:191:in `generate_dashboard_controller'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/namespace.rb:43:in `initialize'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/application.rb:110:in `new'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin/application.rb:110:in `find_or_create_namespace'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:39:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems/active_admin-bbdbadafe5d7/lib/active_admin.rb:70:in `setup'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:556:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `each'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:555:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config.ru:1:in `new'
  from /Users/chance/code/rails/nokr/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.3/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
  from /Users/chance/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an order of op issue on the initializers. Rails loads initializers based on alphabetical order rather than gem decleration (which is what I had originally thought).

For whatever reason, once I introduced configuration options it was attempting to load/parse the User object (a devise model that wasn't an admin_user) and blowing up as Devise had not yet been initialized.

Changing initializers/active_admin.rb to initializers/x_active_admin.rb resolved this issue.